# Openssl rand base64 except capital letters. Command line. How?

Tags: linux, command-line, openssl

I use openssl rand in command line to generate password. I use `openssl rand -base64 10` to generate password. But i need to exclude capital letters? e.g. how to generate 10 random symbols exclude capital letters? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is no direct way to do that, but you can create a much longer "normal" string and then massage it via `sed`:

Assuming you use 16 characters, just do `openssl rand -base64 48 | sed 's/[A-Z]//g ; s/^\(.\{16\}\).*/\1/'`

Answer (score 0):

`openssl rand -base64 10` generates *more* than 10 symbols. It generates 10 bytes (which may correspond to non-printable characters) and encodes them (using a set of printable characters).

To generate random symbols from a given set use `tr`. Example:

```
LC_ALL=C </dev/urandom tr -cd '[:lower:][:digit:]+\-._' | head -c 10 ; printf '\n'
```

Here `tr` receives bytes from `/dev/urandom` and passes only matching ones; `head` terminates the pipe when the given number of characters is reached; `printf` adds a newline.

Check [`man 1 tr`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/tr) and build your own desired set.

Notes:

- `LC_ALL=C` makes `tr` ignore your locale.
- I escaped `-` (hence `\-`) because `tr` interprets `+-.` as a range; `,` is inside this range. I meant `+-._` literally, not including `,`.